# Asumidísimo meaning

Tags: significado-en-contexto

I can't find the meaning of the word **asumidisimo**. I checked in RAE.
Is it a version of "asumido" as in I really assumed? I saw it in "El País".

> Tengo **asumidísimo** que nunca tendré jubilación ni un piso

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, **asumidísimo** is the superlative form of **asumido**.
The suffix **-ísimo** is the equivalent of **-est** in English.
**Asumido** as an adjective is directly taken from the participle of the verb **asumir**.

According to the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/asumir)

**asumir**

> 2. tr. Hacerse cargo, responsabilizarse de algo, aceptarlo.

**In English**

> Take charge, take responsibility for something, accept it

[-**ísimo**](https://dle.rae.es/-%C3%ADsimo?m=form)

> 1. suf. U. para formar el grado superlativo de adjetivos y de algunos adverbios

You can check the meaning of **-est** in the Oxford Dictionary and see for yourself that they match almost perfectly.

[**-est**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-est)

> Forming the superlative of adjectives (such as shortest, widest), and
> of adverbs (such as soonest).

The explanation provided by the DLE about a superlative is not clear. Let's take a look to the [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlativo).

**superlativo** (superlative)

> Un adjetivo en grado superlativo, también llamado comparativo de
> excelencia, expresa la característica en su grado máximo

Answer (score 0):

I would translate 'asumidísimo' as 'very aware of':

> I'm very aware of that I will never have a retirement plan ...

Comment: That does not add to the existing answer and your translation is not correct I am afraid.

Comment: Does it become,"...ísima" for gender agreement?

Comment: I dont think the translation is wrong, there is a modism in the sentence which is "piso" that is how folks in Spain call it to refer to rent an apartment. In any case the sufix ...isimo is offten attached to random words and means awsome or supertight ends the word that wants to be amazing. e.g. Divertidisimo (superfun). And @Bluelion7 your are right with the gender agreement.... isima is female and isimo is male